# Laravel access authenticated user in global scope

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I have a multi-user application with the following entity/model relationship.

**User** belongs to a **Company** and has many **SupportTicket**

Users of one company should not have access to the support tickets of other companies - if a user of one company navigates to a url pointing to a support ticket of another company, they should receive a 404 or something equivalent.

I was hoping to define a global scope in the SupportTicket class as follows:

```
class SupportTicket extends Model {

    protected $fillable = ['company_id'];

    public static function boot() {
        static::addGlobalScope('ofCompany', function(Builder $builder) {
            $authUser = auth()->user();

            $builder->where('company_id', $authUser->company_id);
        });
    }

}
```

The benefit of a global scope is that it will apply to all queries. Other developers working on the project need not work when retrieving tickets as the right results will always be returned.

For example `SupportTicket::all()` or `SupportTicket::find(5)` will always restrict access by user's company.

The challenge I have now is that `auth()->user()` always returns null as the authenticate middleware has not yet been run.

1. Is there a way around this?
2. Has anyone here faced a similar problem and if so how did they go around it?
3. Is it possible to access the authenticated user in the boot method where the global scope is registered?

Many thanks in advance for any and all responses.

Comment: Check this link out (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#5.3-session-in-constructors) it talks about how you can call the middleware manually inside the controller constructor, maybe you can use that to run the middleware manually...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Model filters based on the currently authenticated user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665819/model-filters-based-on-the-currently-authenticated-user)

Comment: @Amade thanks for pointing me to it. From that question, I have found the solution. It links to a [global scope issue on github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/22316) which details a really nice solution.

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 5.6.26 introduced `Auth::hasUser()` to determine if the current user is already authenticated without querying the User model in your database. You can find more details at https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-6-26

So you could do something like this:

```
static::addGlobalScope('ofCompany', function(Builder $builder) {
    if( auth()->hasUser() ){
        $builder->where('company_id', auth()->user()->company_id);
    }     
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check inside the boot method if there's an authenticated user using \Auth::check() before calling \Auth::user().
If the Auth middleware is wrapping routes or the controller itself then you can access the authenticated user anywhere using the facade \Auth::user()

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Tymon's JWT Auth package, you can get auth user like this

```
$authUser = \JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
```